# "Unknown function: <SNR>37_repo_dir" when opening a new file in vim

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I recently updated oh-my-zsh, vim and ran rcup to update dotfiles and vim plugins.

When opening a new file in vim I get an error, part of which contains:

```
Unknown function: <SNR>37_repo_dir
```

This seems to be related to the `fugitive` plugin that I have installed as it is mentioned above the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vim syntax in one of the previously existing `fugitive.vim` configuration files is invalid for in the latest version of vim. fugitive.vim was removed from the latest version of thoughtbot/dotfiles. Since rcup only replaces files dotfiles and doesn't delete them if they were removed from the dotfiles folder the fugitive.vim file needs to be manually removed.

The most straightforward thing to do is:

```
rm -rf ~/.vim && rcup
```

Comment: This is a brute force solution which shouldn't be the recommended answer. `~/.vim` directory could contains key configs.

Comment: @AnthonyAwuley Actually, it is not brute force. Local config changes should be managed in local-dotfiles directory ideally under version control. The .vim directory is generated by rcup using files in dotfiles and local-dogfiles directories.